# How to decide if a file descriptor is attached to a file or socket in Linux

Tags: c, linux, sockets, unix, posix

Using C language in Linux, how to decide if a file descriptor is attached to a file or socket?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `getsockopt` to get `SO_TYPE` on the file descriptor. If it is not a socket, it will return `-1` with the error `ENOTSOCK`:

```
int fd = /* ... */;
bool is_socket;
int socket_type;
socklen_t length = sizeof(socket_type);

if(getsockopt(fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_TYPE, &socket_type, &length) != -1) {
    is_socket = true;
} else {
    if(errno == ENOTSOCK) {
        is_socket = false;
    } else {
        abort();  /* genuine error */
    }
}

/* whether it is a socket will be stored in is_socket */
```

Comment: It seems that I can just do some socket operation on this fd. If it is not a socket fd, the operation will result a error.

Answer (score 7):

Alternatively, you can use `fstat` and the `S_ISSOCK` macro.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int fds[2];

    fds[0] = 0; //stdin
    fds[1] = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i)
    {
        struct stat statbuf;

        if (fstat(fds[i], &statbuf) == -1)
        {
            perror("fstat");
            exit(1);
        }

        if (S_ISSOCK(statbuf.st_mode))
            printf("%d is a socket\n", fds[i]);
        else
            printf("%d is NOT a socket\n", fds[i]);
    }

    return(0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [socket(7) man page](http://linux.die.net/man/7/socket):

> Seeking, or calling pread(2) or pwrite(2) with a nonzero position is not supported on sockets.

So, another option would be to do one of those unsupported operations and see if you get an error. If you managed to seek, then FD is probably a file (or a device). Otherwise it may be a socket.  Or a pipe.